# Cannot increase or decrease brightness in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, brightness

In my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, there is some issue with brightness. It becomes unstable and I cannot increases or decrease brightness. In the login page where the users login, it works properly. Can anyone give solutions to this problem?

Comment: Can you provide more information on your hardware?

Comment: I've made an  edit to your this question, please review it and feel free to rollback it to your original post again.